# Replace dot in entire file with NA without altering data structure

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to replace dot(.) with NA but my current code is replacing even . form a decimal point eg form 0.01. I am using

```
cat input.tsv |  sed -r 's/\./NA/g' > replaced.tsv
```

I have copied hear one of the input lines.

```
1   69091   A   C   M   L   .   1   69091   1   58954   OR4F5   +   ATG 1   0   a   ./. ./. ENSG00000186092 ENST00000335137 ENSP00000334393 1   0.13    0.26702 T   Q8NH21  OR4F5_HUMAN 1   0.0 0.02634 B   0.0 0.01257 B   0.589091    0.05577 N   1.339740    .   .   .   .   .   OR4F5_HUMAN M1L .   .   .   6.76    0.00529 T   -0.38   0.13435 N   NM_001005484.1  M1L 0.12    0.13350 -0.9577 0.39629 T   0.0009  0.00318 T   8   0.00708247797993    0.18931 T   0.109   0.31349 0.823   0.93536 Q8NH21  M1L Loss of sheet (P = 0.0817); Loss of disorder (P = 0.091); Loss of catalytic residue at V2 (P = 0.3992); Loss of solvent accessibility (P = 0.5485); Gain of helix (P = 0.5668)  -1.436194   0.01840 0.003   0.44378301154325944 0.03370 0.02063 0.06083 N   AEFI    c   -1.39413139690747   0.1192561   -1.53570515685522   0.09493324  0.02038 2.2163971633957E-5  0.03550 0.487112    0.13308 0   0.573888    0.26071 0   0.573888    0.22998 0   0.564101    0.26208 0   2.31    -4.63   0.03101 -0.055000   0.11668 -1.983000   0.00506 0.000000    0.06329 0.000000    0.01567 0.2547:0.0:0.5282:0.2171    3.5592  0.07372 .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
```

Desired output

```
1    69091   A   C   M   L   NA   1   69091   1   58954   OR4F5   +   ATG 1   0   a ./. ./. ENSG00000186092 ENST00000335137 ENSP00000334393 1   0.13    0.26702 T   Q8NH21  OR4F5_HUMAN 1   0.0 0.02634 B   0.0 0.01257 B   0.589091    0.05577 N   1.339740    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  OR4F5_HUMAN M1L NA  NA  NA  6.76    0.00529 T   -0.38   0.13435 N   NM_001005484.1  M1L 0.12    0.13350 -0.9577 0.39629 T   0.0009  0.00318 T   8   0.00708247797993    0.18931 T   0.109   0.31349 0.823   0.93536 Q8NH21  M1L Loss of sheet (P = 0.0817); Loss of disorder (P = 0.091); Loss of catalytic residue at V2 (P = 0.3992); Loss of solvent accessibility (P = 0.5485); Gain of helix (P = 0.5668)  -1.436194   0.01840 0.003   0.44378301154325944 0.03370 0.02063 0.06083 N   AEFI    c   -1.39413139690747   0.1192561   -1.53570515685522   0.09493324  0.02038 2.2163971633957E-5  0.03550 0.487112    0.13308 0   0.573888    0.26071 0   0.573888    0.22998 0   0.564101    0.26208 0   2.31    -4.63   0.03101 -0.055000   0.11668 -1.983000   0.00506 0.000000    0.06329 0.000000    0.01567 0.2547:0.0:0.5282:0.2171    3.5592  0.07372 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: So what is your issue?

Comment: Are you trying to replace `.` with `NA` or trying to replace `<blank>.` with `NA` or something else?

Comment: It is a column without any value denoted by `.` to maintain the table structure. All the field is separated by a tab. I need to replace all these `.` with `NA`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this?

```
sed -E 's/(^| )\.( |$)/ NA/g' file
```

looks for a dot with surrounding spaces, also checking for line start or line end.  You need to eat up one of the spaces though.  I chose right one.

Comment: `'s/(^| )\.( |$)/\1NA\2/g'` would leave every space/line-start/line-end as-is and ONLY replace every standalone `.` with `NA`. I'm not sure if that's what the OP wants or not though.

Comment: I think one of the spaces needs to be replaced to keep the alignment of the other fields.  Not sure left of right.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure, I was just considering that it'd ADD a space if the dot was at the start of the line. I guess the OP will let us know...